# Secure Codeigniter application not able to connect to MySQL DB?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, ssl

I am building a secure web application. Currently, **my application runs well using http**.  As soon as I access my application using https, I get the following error:

> Database Error: Unable to connect to the database:Could not connect to
>   MySQL

What are the complete steps to make the application secure? After reading few blogs, I did change the $config['base_url']   property to have:

```
$config['base_url'] = 'https://example.com';
```

and my database.php is:

```
$active_group = 'default';
$active_record = TRUE;

$db['default']['hostname'] = 'host';
$db['default']['username'] = 'root';
$db['default']['password'] = 'pass';
$db['default']['database'] = 'qwt';
$db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'mysql';
$db['default']['dbprefix'] = '';
$db['default']['pconnect'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['db_debug'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['cache_on'] = FALSE;
$db['default']['cachedir'] = '';
$db['default']['char_set'] = 'utf8';
$db['default']['dbcollat'] = 'utf8_general_ci';
$db['default']['swap_pre'] = '';
$db['default']['autoinit'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['stricton'] = FALSE;
```

But I still get the error (I am sure its not the URL property issue). What else do I have to do to get the application successfully running?

Comment: Have you configured your `database.php` file?

Comment: yup.. the application works fine when I am accessing it using http..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Speak to your host.  Sounds like they might have a different connection to use with https

Comment: Thanks for that answer.. it opened up lots of things.. It seems I need to enable the SSL on mysql server too.. But I don't need that (I need SSL only between browser and web server).. any clue?

Comment: Is the SECURE server the sam server as the one that isn't SSL?

Comment: Yes, I guess.. my hosting is third-party and they are the same server.  When I connect from PHP, I use the host as `localhost`..